# sql loader- files with carriage return, line feed load into oracle with cr/lf

Tags: sql-server, oracle, oracle11g, sql-loader

I have data extract from sql server where data in most columns have carriage return and line feeds. I need to load them into oracle with the carriage return and line feed; basically I have to mirror the data form sql server 2012 to oracle 11g.

below is the sample of my extract file

[#BOR#][#EOC#]109[#EOC#]4[#EOC#]testdata_Duplicate[#EOC#]testdata_Duplicate from chat[#EOC#]this

is

```
     carriage return  field[#EOC]test2[#EOR#]
```

Here [#EOC#] is column delimiter, [#EOR#] is row delimiter. [#BOR#] indicates the beginning of row. Initially my loads failed to due to blank lines in the flat file(data extract). Then I used [#BOR#] with continueIf preserve clause so that sqlldr will not treat blank lines(cr/lf) as physical row.

with [#BOR#] as a filler column my load works fine but carriage return or line feed are not loaded into oracle tables.

My ctl file is as below

```
load data
truncate 
CONTINUEIF NEXT preserve (1:7) <> "[#BOR#]"
into table sch1.tbl1
fields terminated by '[#EOC#]'
trailing nullcols (
  field       filler,   
  a_id        integer external,
  h_id        integer external,
  title       char(128),
  descn       char(4000),
  risk        char(4000),
  comment     char(4000) terminated by '[#EOR#]')
```

In oracle sch1.tbl1 table column risk has data as 'this is carriage return field' instead of 
'this

is

```
     carriage return  field'
```

I tried to replace char(10) with string [#crlf#] and use replace function in ctl like as below

```
load data
    truncate 
    CONTINUEIF NEXT preserve (1:7) <> "[#BOR#]"
    into table sch1.tbl1
    fields terminated by '[#EOC#]'
    trailing nullcols (
      field       filler,   
      a_id        integer external,
      h_id        integer external,
      title       char(128),
      descn       char(4000),
      risk        char(4000) "replace(:risk,[#crlf#],chr(10))"
      comment     char(4000) terminated by '[#EOR#]')
```

the sql loader errors out stating SQL*Loader-309: No SQL string allowed as part of field specification; I believe because my columns are CLOB data type I am not able to use replace function.

Please help me to load data from sql server with cr/lnFeed into oracle tables using sqlloader. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution that works for me. 
Instead of replacing the carriage return/line feed(cr/lf) in the extracted flat file with [#crlf#] I retain the cr/lf in the extracted data file.
And then I changed my ctl file to handle the cr/lf with INFILE Clause with file name and " str '\n' ". For Unix env we need \n where in for windows we can use either \n or \r\n.

see below

```
load data INFILE 'filename.dat' "str '\n'" 
    truncate 
    CONTINUEIF NEXT preserve (1:7) <> "[#BOR#]"
    into table sch1.tbl1
    fields terminated by '[#EOC#]'
    trailing nullcols (
      field       filler,   
      a_id        integer external,
      h_id        integer external,
      title       char(128),
      descn       char(4000),
      risk        char(4000),
      comment     char(4000) terminated by '[#EOR#]')
```

I tested it and data loaded with cr\lf.. I need to do more detailed testing, as of now I have tested one table I have many more.
Meanwhile if any one has better solution I would be more than happy to try it out.

Comment: For embedded CR/LFs, `"STR 'EndOfRecord\n'"` can be used in the control file. Try this please: `LOAD DATA INFILE * "STR '[EOR]\n' INTO TABLE your_table APPEND FIELDS TERMINATED BY "[#EOC#]" TRAILING NULLCOLS ( ..., comment char(4000))`.